# LDAP filter for blank (empty) attribute

Tags: ldap

I have searched on this topic, but all I find are filters that return entries where a certain attribute is not present, like:

```
(!(manager=*))
```

However, I want to find entries where the attribute is present, but has a null value (i.e. an empty/blank string). Can I do this using an LDAP filter, and if so, how?

EDIT:

Just to confirm, the above filter finds entries without the attribute, but not where the attribute is empty (null string).

Is this dependent on the LDAP implementation or what?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From LDAP, there is not a query method to determine an empty string.

The best practice would be to scrub your data inputs to LDAP as an empty or null value in LDAP is no value at all.

To determine this you would need to query for all with a value (manager=*) and then use code to determine the ones that were a "space" or null value.

And as Terry said, storing an empty or null value in an attribute of DN syntax is wrong.

Some LDAP server implementations will not permit entering a DN where the DN entry does not exist.

Perhaps, you could, if your DN's are consistent, use something like:

```
(&(!(manager=cn*))(manager=*))
```

This should return any value of manager where there was a value for manager and it did not start with "cn".

However, some LDAP implementations will not allow sub-string searches on DN syntax attributes.

-jim

Comment: Somehow everyone seemed to get sidetracked on schema and such issues; my question was whether there is a way to *filter* such entries, and you came closest to answering that by telling me that I would have to, in my client code, filter out such entries, which is what I feared, but which I suppose is right. Accepted, thanks.

Comment: There is no sidetrack: the schema plays a role in determining which types of filters can be used. Assertions are dependent on the type of the attribute, it's syntax, and its ordering and matching rules. This is how  assertions work.

Answer (score 9):

Search for a null value by using `\00`

For example:

```
ldapsearch -D cn=admin -w pass -s sub -b ou=users,dc=acme 'manager=\00' uid manager
```

Make sure if you use the null value on the command line to use quotes around it to prevent the OS shell from sending a null character to LDAP.  For example, this won't work:

```
 ldapsearch -D cn=admin -w pass -s sub -b ou=users,dc=acme manager=\00 uid manager
```

There are various sites that reference this, along with other special characters.  Example:

- http://www.ldapexplorer.com/en/manual/109010000-ldap-filter-syntax.htm
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Powershell, with the RSAT activedirectory module. This feature may be a happy accident of the `ldapsearch` implementation you're using.

Answer (score 9):

This article http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198810.aspx led me to the solution. The only change is the placement of the exclamation mark.

```
(!manager=*)
```

It seems to be working just as wanted.

Comment: ldap_search_ext: Bad search filter (-7)

Comment: The recent edit conflicted with the author's intent, and resulted in the post merely reiterating what the OP already had. However the original answer, which I have restored, is invalid syntax, and the linked article is incorrect, except apparently in the case of MS Active Directory, which is already known to be rather non-compliant with the LDAP RFCs..

Answer (score 3):

Semantically there is no difference between these cases in LDAP.

Comment: You would think so, yet I cannot use the above filter to select such entities! (i.e. where the attribute is present but blank).

Comment: Just to confirm, it allows me to find entries without the attribute, but not where the attribute is empty (null string).

Comment: @mydoghasworms You've missed my point entirely. You are making a distinction without a difference.

Answer (score 3):

I needed to do a query to get me all groups with a managedBy value set (not empty) and this gave some nice results:

```
(!(!managedBy=*))
```

Comment: This is the opposite answer.

Comment: It is also invalid syntax.

Comment: (managedBy=*) works fine for this.

Answer (score 2):

The schema definition for an attribute determines whether an attribute must have a value. If the `manager` attribute in the example given is the attribute defined in [RFC4524](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4524#section-2.17) with OID `0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.10`, then that attribute has DN syntax. DN syntax is a sequence of relative distinguished names and **must not be empty**. The filter given in the example is used to cause the LDAP directory server to return only entries that do not have a `manager` attribute to the LDAP client in the search result.

Answer (score 0):

You have to negate matching the wildcard * (any value) :

```
(&(objectCategory=computer)(whenCreated>=20160101000000.0Z)(!description=*))
```

From Microsoft's LDAP Query Basics:

> The ! operator in conjunction with the wildcard operator will look for objects where that attribute is not set to anything.